# how to set environment for multi tenant in for spring application?

Tags: java, spring, multi-tenant

I have to make one application in multi tenant using spring framework and eclipse IDE. I have created environment for spring programming. But how to create setup for multi tenant in it.

And from where i have to start making multi tenant application using spring?

Thanks for reply in advance.

Comment: Multitenancy is done in YOUR application architecture and not as part of a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by designing your application to support multiple client organizations. There is no built in support for this from Spring side.
I have also participated in such application using Spring's routing datasource. You can read more at:

1. http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/
2. [Dynamic DataSource Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304019/dynamic-datasource-routing)